# Using Graph API to Add Keys to Service Principals

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use this endpoint to create a service principal and simultaneously create a key, which according to MS documentation([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-addkey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) should be possible
"Create servicePrincipal and Update servicePrincipal operations can continue to be used to add and update key credentials for any servicePrincipal with or without a user's context."

POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals

My body looks like this:

```
{
  "appId": "65415bb1-9267-4313-bbf5-ae259732ee12",
              "keyCredentials": [{
                "key"         : "redacted",
                "type"        : "Symmetric",
                "usage"       : "Verify"
            }]
}
```

but Postman is throwing this error:

Cannot convert the literal 'redacted' to the expected type 'Edm.Binary'.

Has anyone run into this issue? Or better yet, has anyone been able to create a service principal for an app registration using the graph API and also create/add the key? The post to this endpoint works fine when only including the APPID in the body.

Tried using both the direct endpoint:

POST

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$Id/addKey
```

and also the standard one to add the service principal

POST

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
```

I would expect them to succeed and create the serviceprincipal/add the key

Comment: key --> The certificate's raw data in byte array converted to Base64 string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Answer (score 1):

The `key` property of `keyCredential` should contain the certificate's raw data in byte array converted to Base64 string.

You are using the correct endpoint, but you need to convert certificate's raw data to Base64 string.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
```

Body

```
{
    "appId": "65415bb1-9267-4313-bbf5-ae259732ee12",
    "keyCredentials": [{
        "key": "<certificate_raw_data_in_base64>",
        "type": "Symmetric",
        "usage": "Verify"
    }]
}
```

Documentation

[keyCredential - properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to add the key simultaneously while creating the service principle, As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , you have to create the service principle first using the App Id .

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
Content-type: application/json

{
"appId": "65415bb1-9267-4313-bbf5-ae259732ee12"
}

Once the SP created you will get the empty "keyCredentials": [] in response, doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1

Now you will follow the same [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-addkey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples.) to add key.

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/addKey](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/%7Bid%7D/addKey)
Content-type: application/json

```
{
    "keyCredential": {
        "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
        "usage": "Verify",
        "key": "MIIDYDCCAki..."
    },
    "passwordCredential": null,
    "proof":"eyJ0eXAiOiJ..."
}
```

Request body required 3 property keyCredential , passwordCredential , proof ,
[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXZIh.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXZIh.png)

Hope this helps

Thanks